# Let $n$ be a natural number s.t. every natural number less than $n/2$ divides $n$. Prove $n$ is less than or equal to $6$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ be a natural number s.t. every natural number less than $n/2$ divides $n$. Prove $n$ is less than or equal to $6$.

From an intro to algebra text I'm reading. Need hint on how to go about proving it.

Comment: Hint:  first assume some counterexample $n$ is odd, so $n=2k+1$.  your assumption tells us that $k$ and $k-1$ both divide $n$ and, as they are relatively prime, their product must divide $n$.  Now argue that $k(k-1)>n$ except for small $k$.  Find a similar argument for $n=2k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $n>6$.

We first prove that $n$ is not odd.  Assume, for contradiction, that $n$ is odd.  Then $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\geq 3$ and $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor-1\geq 2$.  Therefore, both $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ and $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor-1$ divide $n$, but one of them is even, so $n$ is even.  This is a contradiction.

We now prove that $n$ is not even.  Assume that, for contradiction, that $n$ is even.  Let $n=2k$.  Since $n>6$, $k>3$.  Therefore, $k-1>2$ and $k-2>1$.  Since both $k-1$ and $k-2$ divide $n$ and are relatively prime, $(k-1)(k-2)$ divides $n$.  Hence $(k-1)(k-2)\leq 2k$.  By multiplying this out and simplifying, $k^2-5k+3\leq0$.  Using the quadratic formula, we find that $$\frac{5-\sqrt{13}}{2}\leq k\leq \frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2}.$$
Therefore, the largest that $n$ could be is $5+\sqrt{13}\approx 8.6055.$  The only even number less than $8.6055$ and greater than $6$ is $8$.  But $3$ is less than $\frac{8}{2}=4$ and does not divide $8$.  This excludes $8$.  Therefore, there are no such $n$'s, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Delta(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$, then $\Delta(n)\le 2\sqrt n$, therefore $$\frac n2-1\le\Delta(n)\le2\sqrt{n}$$ which cannot be true when $n\ge 20$.

Cases $6<n\le19$ can be easily checked.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n>11$. Then $n$ is even and $\gcd(n/2-1, n/2-2)=1$ and they both divide $n$ so $(n/2-1)(n/2-2)$ divides $n$, so $(n/2-1)(n/2-2)$ is smaller or equal to $n$. One easily checks that this is not possible for $n>11$, so $n \leq 11$, and now you can check every number less than $11$.